# How to share Power Query queries

Tags: microsoft-excel, cloud, azure, query, power-query

I was looking for a way to share Power Query queries.

I am not sure on how to share query in the intranet. Seems like sharing in Power Query Data Catalog is named "Power BI Data Catalog". This is afaik cloud solution which is set up in "Office 365". How to share Queries locally to the enterprise? Should I use Microsoft Azure Pack to create own cloud and what additional software do I need to run in this cloud to enable sharing Power Query queries?

Answer (score 2):

Power BI for Office 365 was discontinued:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-frequently-asked-questions/#what-has-happened-to-the-power-bi-for-office-365-experience

The replacement functionality to share datasets in the current Power BI service would be "Organizational Content Packs":

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-organizational-content-packs-introduction/